# How do I Remove(using a mouseover) a display none(CSS) with Jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

i am making a card nft project to practice where when i mouseover it should remove the display:none from the HTML class="nft" . I tried many things also only using CSS but i didn't achieve the results. If anyone could help me or give a explanation to make help I really apreciate.
HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nft').on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).toggle();
     });
});
```

```css
.img-text{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 10px 25px;
}

.nft{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: cyan;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.eye{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 40%;
}
.nft-image{
    max-height: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-text">
   <div class="nft">
       <img src="./img/icon-view.svg" alt="" class="eye">
    </div>
    <img class="nft-image" src="./img/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="NFT">
    <h1 class="heading">Equilibrium #3429</h1>
</div>
```

I tried using Hover with CSS, add and removing classes in html and using jquery but no result

Thank you

Comment: When something is `display:none` it's completely hidden from the page.  This means there's nothing there for your mouse to move over at all. It doesn't exist.  You can't hover over what you can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to make it invisible in another way such as this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  let show = true
  $('.nft').on('mouseover', function () {
$(this).css('background-color', show ? 'cyan' : '')
show = !show
  })
})
```

```css
.img-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 10px 25px;
}

.nft {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.eye {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
}
.nft-image {
  max-height: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;

  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-text">
  <div class="nft">
<img src="./img/icon-view.svg" alt="" class="eye" />
  </div>
  <img class="nft-image" src="./img/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="NFT" />
  <h1 class="heading">Equilibrium #3429</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful but i did and it worked but i forget to mention that i also need the mouseleave option and i found lwrote like this in jquery 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nft-image').on('mouseover', function() {
        $('.nft').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    $('.img-text').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('.nft').addClass('hidden');
    });
}); 
and also i added the class hidden alone with display: none.
Thank you very much